# Convergence of a series in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis

This is probably a very easy exercise or a consequence of some theorem but somehow I am not really sure of the following statement. Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions in $L^2(\Omega).$ Suppose this is a probability space for now. Define the following function $$g(x)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a_n f_n(x)$$

Is it true if $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} |a_n|^2<\infty $ and $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$ then the series converges in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Comment: No. For example $\Omega=[0,1]$, $f_n=1$, $a_n=1/n$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh yes. Is there some condition that can be used to check if such a series converges in L^2?

Comment: I don't know about "checking" convergence, but of course if the $f_n$ are orthonormal the series converges.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich is this a theorem? Do you mind citing a source that I can look up to see how this is proved?

Comment: Look up "orthonormal set", or maybe "inner product space" somewhere...

Comment: Or prove it yourself; it's trivial to show  the norm of the tail tends to $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two conditions under which the series converges in $L^{2}$:

1) $(f_n)$ is orthonormal: in this case you can show that the partial sums  form a Cauchy sequence in $L^{2}$ and use completeness of $L^{2}$

2) $f=0$ and  $\sum \|f_n\|^{2} <\infty$: in this case use the fact that $|\sum_k^{j} a_nf_n(x)|^{2} \leq \sum_k^{j} |a_n|^{2} \sum_k^{j} |f_n(x)|^{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a condition that various readers may find not so boring:

> > Suppose $\delta(h)\ge0$ for $h\in\Bbb Z$ and $c^2=\sum_{h\in\Bbb Z}\delta(h)<\infty$. If (on some measure space) $|\int f_j\overline{f_k}|\le\delta(j-k)$ and $s=\sum_{j=-N}^Na_jf_j$ then $||s||_2^2\le c^2\sum|a_j|^2.$
> >
> > **Corollary.** If in addition $\sum|a_j|^2<\infty$ then $\sum a_jf_j$ converges in $L^2$.

**Note** if $(f_j)$ is orthonormal the hypothesis is satisfied with $\delta(0)=1$, $\delta(h)=0$ for $h\ne0$.

**Proof:** We simplify the notation by regarding $a_j$ as defined for every $j\in\Bbb Z$, with $a_j=0$ for $|j|>N$. Starting from $|s|^2=s\overline s$ and multiplying out the product we obtain $$||s||_2^2=\sum_{j,k}a_j\overline{a_k}\int f_j\overline{f_k}
=\sum_{h\in\Bbb Z}\sum_{j\in\Bbb Z}a_j\overline{a_{j+h}}\int f_j\overline{f_{j+h}}.$$For each $h\in\Bbb Z$ Cauchy-Schwarz implies
$$\left|\sum_{j\in\Bbb Z}a_j\overline{a_{j+h}}\int f_j\overline{f_{j+h}}\right|\le\delta(h)(\sum|a_j|^2)^{1/2}(\sum_j|a_{j+h}|^2)^{1/2}=\delta(h)\sum|a_j|^2.$$

**Exercise.** Suppose in addition that $||f_j||_2=1$ and $d=\left(\sum_{h\ne0}\delta(h)\right)^{1/2}<1$. Then $||s||_2^2\ge(1-d)^2\sum|a_j|^2$.

I think it's $(1-d)^2$ anyway, may be some other constant.

One can use this to show for example that if $|k_n-n|$ is small enough then $\sum a_je^{ik_jt}$ behaves like a Fourier series...